# Looping off of MySQL result and building custom array

Tags: php, mysql

The following code is building the proper structure of array that I want, but it's only doing it for one result even though the MYSQL result is about 65 items.

I need the 'type' and 'features' levels to be static, and then start the loop within the features level (so every mysql result would build an item in within the features level)

The following is only loading the last result from the query:

```
$db->setQuery($query);
$item=$db->loadObjectList();
echo $db->getErrorMsg();
//dump($item);

$stores = [
    'type' => 'FeatureCollection',
    'features' => [
      foreach ($item as $i) {
        [
            'type' => 'Feature',
            'geometry' => [
                'type' => 'Point',
                'coordinates' => [
                    $i->lat,
                    $i->lng
                ]
            ],
            'properties' => [
                'storeImage' => $i->logo, // you need to convert this into an actual URL
                'storeName' => $i->name,
                'phoneFormatted' => $i->phone, // this needs formatting aswell
                'address' => $i->address,
                'city' => $i->city,
                'country' => $i->country,
                'postalCode' => $i->zip,
                'state' => $i->state
            ]
        ]
      }
    ]
];
```

How can I properly loop the mysql query to build my array in the correct way?

Comment: This isn't even valid syntax, you can't put a `foreach` inside an array element. You could use `array_map()`

Comment: What does this have to do with JavaScript or JSON?

Comment: I should have removed those tags, the original question had where I was returning the json_encoded version into a javascript constant, but I realized I just needed to solve this at the array building level. Checking out your answe3r now, but it's giving me a syntax error. I think I see why though

Comment: The `;` in the middle of the array was wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `array_map()` to generate a new array from another array.

```
$item=$db->loadObjectList();

$stores = [
    'type' => 'FeatureCollection',
    'features' => array_map(function($i) {
        return [
            'type' => 'Feature',
            'geometry' => [
                'type' => 'Point',
                'coordinates' => [
                    $i->lat,
                    $i->lng
                ]
            ],
            'properties' => [
                'storeImage' => $i->logo, // you need to convert this into an actual URL
                'storeName' => $i->name,
                'phoneFormatted' => $i->phone, // this needs formatting aswell
                'address' => $i->address,
                'city' => $i->city,
                'country' => $i->country,
                'postalCode' => $i->zip,
                'state' => $i->state
            ]
        ];
    }, $item)
];
```

Comment: After the update it still seems to be giving the ```unexpected `}, item` expectinvg `;` ``` error

Comment: There was a missing semicolon, check the updated answer

Comment: Thanks so much, I got it working now! I'm also converting the logo and phone into proper formats